# multiple params in a mysql statement

Tags: mysql

i use this statement for a single where condition
('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', 1)

if I want to check two conditions, how would I do that

('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND age=?', 1,23)- is this correct?

Comment: depends on which language and library you're using to bind the query! PHP and PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the client library and/or framework you're using.  In most cases, what you've got there is fine.  In others, you have to pass an array, and in others still, you can pass an associative array (or dictionary) and use named values in your query.

If you want a more detailed answer, you need to provide more details.